# Can a widget extend a class besdides Template?

Tags: programmatically, widget, widgets, class, extend

All widgets I have ever created programmatically `extends Template implements BlockInterface` and I was curious if you can extend different classes for a widget module's block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can extend another class when declaring a Widget block but that class should be extended `Template` class for rendering it on the frontend.

For example, you can take a look at `Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link` Widget class: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Widget/Link.php